# Facebook Login with WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, winforms

I have a question im working on a current project where we have a windows forms application i want to login in to facebook how can i manage this i have Facebook.dll in my current project i have an old token when i try

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = Config.APP_ID,
            client_secret = Config.APP_SECRET,
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = Config.ACCESS_TOKEN
        });

        MessageBox.Show(result);
```

i get the following exception:    **Additional information: (OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out**

and is also expired.

how can i let this work and login to my FB account by winforms.

Thanks for the ideas.

Kind Regards

Comment: it also need to be an automatic login

Answer (score 0):

FacebookAPI using accessToken with the limited time.
The only way to do it is: 
-You can pay for a long time access token 
Or - you build a function to get access token after a mount of time. But it force you to login again. So think about automation login as a function!
Hope you like it ^^

Comment: I need something that does'nt expire ?  how can i login than in winforms ?

Comment: Give it a try:  string getAccessTokenURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=545172111163481&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&scope=user_photos,user_videos";